# datetimepicker is not a function Angular

Tags: angular, datetimepicker, angular7

i want to add i datetime picker in angular.

i am using this library  https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

now i am facing following error given below,

> Uncaught TypeError:
>   jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__(...).datetimepicker is not a
>   function

```
<form> <input id="datetimepicker_mask" type="text" ></form>


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import datetimepicker from 'jquery-datetimepicker';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-order',
  templateUrl: './form-order.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-order.component.css']
}) 

export class FormOrderComponent implements OnInit {
    $ : any;
  constructor() { } 

    ngOnInit() {


     $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#datetimepicker_mask').datetimepicker({
      timepicker:false,
      mask:true,
      });
      });



    }

}


[enter image description here][1]
```

### [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ge8c.jpg

```
"scripts": [
              "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "../node_modules/jquery-datetimepicker/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"
```

any reply would be highly appreciated.

Comment: For a [mcve] the HTML and CSS fragments are missing.

Comment: Use a date-time picker package which have Angular native support. That's what recommended. The current package you are using is a pure JQuery which is not so good to use with Angular.

Answer (score -2):

Just need to adding `datetimepicker` object in `ngOnInit` function

```
ngOnInit(){
  datetimepicker
}
```

it's work very